# Marketplace - Are apps tied to a specific google account?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are currently attempting to publish an App on the Google Marketplace (aka Chrome Web Store).

My boss has paid the $5 developer fee using his Gsuite account, and when I log in to publish the app, it keeps requesting the $5 fee to be paid. We are both part of the same GSuite domain (rulerr.com). I'm guessing this means the payment is tied to his account specifically? Is there any way to get this tied to our Gsuite domain?

As a result of the way this works, if I end up publishing using my account can anyone delegated from my domain modify it? If I was to go on vacation/sick leave/move on to another company then noone in my organization would be able to modify the App details?

Would adding a shared mailbox account specifically for marketplace registration alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laurie,

You can create a Google Group and use that as the owner of your app.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing

Any member of that group will then be able to publish. (when they have paid the 5$ fee)